# How to generate jasper reports from mongodb without using Jaspersoft MongoDB Query Language?

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, jasper-reports, spring-data

I want to generate jasper reports for some data i have in my database(mongo db ).
I have researched a bit and know that we can do this using Jaspersoft mongodb query language,but i don want to use it .
I want to get the data from mongodb using either java driver/spring data and provide that data to jasper to generate reports ..
Is this possible ??

Comment: Have you tried any code??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use MongoDB Java driver to query the data, add the returned list to JEBeanCollectionDataSource and pass this datasource to Jasper. That should work.